# How to show percentile of each bin in a histogram with plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, percentile

Is there any method that allow to not only display counts and xaxis value but also display percentile in a histogram? like this picture:

[image: Image of a histogram]

Comment: Percentages can be displayed by doing 'percent' in `histnorm`. `fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", histnorm='percent')` `fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Histogram(x=df['total_bill'],histnorm='percent')])`